# FQL query not returning post likes

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using FQL to get data from post likes, but it returns an empty array

the request:

> https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+like_info+FROM+stream+WHERE+post_id=%27100004594088653_322987734531027%27&format=json&access_token=CAABtxddMK1YBAEBbBkZBiEr0hKWP2jSYqChXz1rw7oan3CaOk4LJYL1giYgfhdMJYrQiUZB3QIz73AGPfHEu16NfocIbhVwFYcW7w9VTBuUEy1wYkGkOHLlZCwQuVnLG6NhgG7lZC8TOTnJZC5L44Yh531uY0JEWdOBEAsBPDgqfNpx1cbeAtmZBp1dcAGVGDOexZBMlLmmeuWkE4l0Yujf&jsonp

the original post:

> https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=322987734531027&id=100004594088653

debug facebook:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20like_info%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%3D%273100004594088653_322987734531027%27

Why is FQL returning an empty array while the original post has likes?

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with the permissions.

See here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions